# Return a string that matches until another given string

Tags: java, string

I can get it done by implementing the logic to do it. However, I am looking for a single method call rather than implement it myself.

Example:

```
String sampleStr = "This is a sample string";
String resultStr = sampleStr.singleMethodCall("sample"); 
//resultStr will be "This is a sample"
```

I am ok if this can be achieved with a third party API.

Comment: I don't understand.. if you can implement this yourself, then why not write the API yourself?

Comment: I know its a fairly trivial implementation. I try not to increase the size of my code base. I will also have to handle every cases and not to mention writing test cases for new code you add. Moreover, why reinvent the wheel if tried and tested third party string manipulators exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard `String` functions.

```
String resultStr = sampleStr.substring(0, sampleStr.indexOf("sample") + 6);
```

Take the substring from position 0 (the start) until the position of "sample", but add another 6 characters so you also include "sample" and the preceeding space.